# Как оцентрировать значение в slider handle JQueryUI?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Как можно оцентрировать значение, которое отражается в ползунке JQuery UI?

Код, вызывающий ползунок

```
var handle = $("#custom-handle");

    $("#slider-dist").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        create: function() {
            handle.text($(this).slider("value"));
        },
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            handle.text(ui.value);
        }
    });
```

Скрин, что получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что значение прижато к левому краю. Как его разместить по центру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вставляете значение в блок `#custom-handle`. В CSS укажите:

```
#custom-handle {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Ну или флексом к примеру:

```
#custom-handle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Работает ) Спасибо! Оказывается все просто. Я думал, нужно лезть куда-то в Jquery UI )

Comment: @NikitaMigushev пришлось бы лезть в стили JQuery хендела если бы Вы не делали свой кастомный, а так всё в разы проще)